# Rails combined ('AND') searches on associated join tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I cant get rails to return combined ('AND') searches on associated join tables of an Object.

E.g. I have Books that are in Categories. Lets say: Book 1: is in category 5 and 8

But I can't get 'AND' to filter results using the join table? E.g ::->

Class Books
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :join_table => "book_categories"

Book.find :all, :conditions => "book_categories.category_id = 5 AND book_categories.category_id = 8", :include => "categories"
... returns nil
(why does it not return all books that are in both 5 & 8 ??)

However: 'OR' does work:

Book.find :all, :conditions => "book_categories.category_id = 5 OR book_categories.category_id = 8"
... returns all books in category 5 and 8

I must be missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at the SQL level. That condition runs on a link table row, and any individual link table row can never have a `category_id` of both 5 and 8. You really want *separate* link table rows to have these IDs.

Try looking into Rails' [`named_scope`](http://millarian.com/2008/8/31/quick-tip-named_scope), specifically the part that allows filtering with a lambda (so you can take an argument). I've never tried it out myself, but if I had to implement what you're looking for, that's what I'd look in to.

Comment: Yeah, you want a result if the category's id is 5 OR 8, because it can never be simultaneously 5 AND 8.